# Isomorphism between subspace of $\operatorname{Mat}_{p,q}(K)\times \operatorname{Mat}_{q,p}(K)$ and $\operatorname{Mat}_{p,q}(K) \times \{0\}$

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm reading the following paper: [The affine preservers of non-singular matrices](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1003.5675.pdf)

Lemma $7$ states: Let $H$ be a $pq$-dimensional linear subspace of $\operatorname{Mat}_{p,q}(\mathbb{K})\times \operatorname{Mat}_{q,p}(\mathbb{K})$($\mathbb{K}$ is any field) with:

(i) $\forall(L, C),(L, C′)\in H^2, \forall P \in \operatorname{GL}_q(\mathbb{K}), LP C′ + L′P C =0. $

.

.

.(assumption (ii) is not related to my question)

Then either $H=\operatorname{Mat}_{p,q}(K) \times \{0\}$ or $H= \{0\} \times \operatorname{Mat}_{p,q}(K)$ or $p=q=1$ and $\mathbb{K} = \mathbb{F}_2\
$.

In the proof, we read:"... **for any $C \in \operatorname{Mat}_{q,p}(K) \setminus \{0\}$, one has $\sum_
{P \in \operatorname{GL}_q(\mathbb{K})}
\operatorname{Im} P C = \mathbb{K}^q$**
.

Assume $(L, C) \mapsto L$ is not one-to-one from $H$ and choose a non-zero $(0, C)$ in
its kernel. Let $(L′, C′) \in H$. *Then (i) shows $\forall P \in \operatorname{GL}_q(\mathbb{K}), L′P C = 0$ hence $L′ = 0$ by the preliminary remark (in bold), and $(L′, C′) \mapsto C′$ is then one-to-one from $H$.*

I don't quite get how we derive the italicised sentence from the remark in bold. I feel like it's some easy trick I'm missing, but how do we end up with $L'=0$ and $(L′, C′) \mapsto C′$ one-to-one?

Comment: Does not the bold remark, together with $L'PC=0$ for all $P$ imply that $L'(\mathbb{K}^q)=0$?

Comment: @ancientmathematician you're right, thanks!